# socket.io and node.js emitting from another file than server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have three files `app.js` `db.js` and `client.html`
`app.js` is server `js` file and `db.js` is the file where I made all the actions with database
I am using sockets to tell user if some changes were made in his orders in database.
But i am using socket io in `app.js` how can i emit from `db.js` when some action is happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your app.js

```
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io=require('./db')(server);
server.listen(5000, (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(' i am listening')
})
```

in your db.js

```
module.exports = function (server) {
let io = require('socket.io')(server)
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
//do you stuff here
 })
}
```